# SQL query to compare current date to match results

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a requirement to check if today's date is equal to create date + 25 days. My DB is Oracle 11g.

If the employee data is created on Nov 1st then then condition should be today = (nov Ist, 25).

My date format is is 03-NOV-17 12.18.11.307000000

I tried this query but it is not working

```
select * 
from employee 
where trunc(sysdate) = to_date(create_date, 'DD/MMM/YY') + 25;
```

I also tried `dateadd`, but that displays an error "not recognized"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `create_date` has a `TIMESTAMP` data type (since you are showing fractional seconds) then you can use:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   employee 
WHERE  create_date >= TRUNC(sysdate) - INTERVAL '25' DAY
AND    create_date <  TRUNC(sysdate) - INTERVAL '24' DAY;
```

*(Which would allow Oracle to use any indexes on the `create_date` column.)*

Alternatively, you could use:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   employee 
WHERE  TRUNC(create_date) = TRUNC(sysdate) - INTERVAL '25' DAY;
```

*(Which would not use any indexes on the `create_date` column; you would require a separate function-based index on `TRUNC(create_date)`.)*